# Intellij IDEA 14 - remove indents on empty lines

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have an annoying bug regarding intellij **14.0.3**. The issue is that it keeps indents on empty lines and I can't remove that whitespace in any way. Under code style, I have not checked the checkbox "keep indents on empty lines" and judging from the display how that functionality works I'd say it would do it.

However, it still keeps the indents and that creates bad diffs in git since whitespace is added. Is this a bug? Can I in any way remove them? I have tried to uncheck that checkbox under both the language I use and the main one. None of them seems to change it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try enabling the *Strip trailing spaces on save* option in Settings/Editor/General.

You can choose whether this should be performed for All lines or only the lines you modify to avoid creating unnecessary diffs.

The whitespace is stripped when you explicitly hit CTRL+S or automatically after some period (IntelliJ has autosaving).

One thing to note is that if you have cursor on an empty line and there are some spaces before it, hitting CTRL + S won't strip the whitespace, because this would probably be annoying as your cursor would jump to the beginning of the line if the file was autosaved by IntelliJ (I read somewhere on YouTrack that this was a design decision).

Here is a screenshot of the option I describe:

[image]

Comment: This is enabled, but it seems it's a bug in the version of intellij I used. I will however accept your answer.

Comment: I don't like the design decision that JetBrains made on this one... but thanks for the diagnosis / explanation

Comment: Appears to be a bug in 2020.1.3 too, i.e. trimming doesn't work as expected.

Comment: For me this behaviour also came up with a recent IntelliJ update, and it's still there with 2020.1.4 (and I made sure that "strip trailing space on save" is activated)! Very annoying, I'm already considering to suspend the TSLint check, but maybe IntelliJ introduce some new setting that is hidden somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Steps using last version **IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Community Edition)**:

<kbd>Menu</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Editor</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> ><kbd>On Save</kbd>

- Remove trailing spaces on: <kbd>[All Lines]</kbd>
- Keep trailing spaces on caret line <kbd>[UnChecked]</kbd>

---

Example:

[image]

---

Now, when you save the edits (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), automatically empty tabs are removed!

Answer (score -2):

What I did to strip spaces without having to open & save each file is running a regex in the find and replace window:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Text to find

   ```
   ^ +\n
   ```

   Find every line that starts with (^) one or more spaces ( +) and nothing else (/n).
3. Replace with:

   ```
   \n
   ```

   A new line.
4. General > Regular expression (obviously important to check this box)
5. Eventually you may want to limit the scope because this will be quite the lengthy operation
6. <kbd>Find</kbd> and eventually <kbd>continue</kbd> if IDEA warns for the high amount of occurrences.
7. Click <kbd>All Files</kbd> to run the actual replace operation. It might take some time before IDEA to respond.